# Вырезать из предложения часть, изменить и вставить обратно

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Имеется такое предложение:

```
"Sum(Dictonary((12 30, 46 72, 87 1043)), Dictonary(1 1, 439534 431213.343, 4343 3)))"
```

Как получить массив:

```
[["12 30", "46 72", "87 1043"], ["1 1", "439534 431213.343", "4343 3"]]
```

Добавить элемент к примеру в эти массивы и вставить обратно в предложение

Пробую найти позицию элементов такой регуляркой, но она работает со словами, а с двумя скобками нет:

```
r'\((([^]]+))\)'
```

через функцию `re.findall`

**UDP**: Такой вариант уже ближе, но остаются лишние скобки

```
^\(\((((?!\[)(?!\]).)+)\)\)
```

**Для модераторов:** что вы подразумеваете под конкретизировать вопрос?

Comment: Это строки или что? Приведите пример, что вы в итоге то на выходе хотите получить? И, главное - зачем это всё?

Comment: А вот пробел в `1 1` оно зачем?

Comment: @CrazyElf массив из элемнтов. Элементы это пара чисел. Нужно проверить элементы и дописать при необходимости

Comment: @AndyPavlov он делит два числа

Comment: @helldrg Не может быть массив, в котором числа пробелом отделены. Это только в строковом виде может быть это всё.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, массив строк и нужен, мой косяк, кавычки не проставил в массиве

Comment: @helldrg Так проставьте кавычки. Это важно, задачи решаются совсем разными в зависимости от того, какие у вас данные.

Comment: @CrazyElf исправил

Comment: А вот которое в начале предложение - это всё строка?

Comment: да, исходные данные это все строка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы разделил обработку на 2 шага:

- Вытаскивание целых сущностей (`Dictonary`)
- Вытаскивание параметров

Пример:

```
import re

text = "Sum(Dictonary((12 30, 46 72, 87 1043)), Dictonary(1 1, 439534 431213.343, 4343 3)))"

items = [
    re.findall(r'[\d.]+ [\d.]+', dict_str)
    for dict_str in re.findall(r'Dictonary\(.+?\)', text)
]
print(items)
# [['12 30', '46 72', '87 1043'], ['1 1', '439534 431213.343', '4343 3']]
```

Comment: То что нужно! Единственное, я в массиве значения поменяю, добавлю элементы и как потом вставить изменные элементы назад?

Answer (score 0):

может, что-то вроде этого подойдет:

- выбираем из стоки "массивы",
- в f() делаем с ними то, что необходимо (для примера добавляем "00 00")
- подставляем в исходную строку

```
from re import sub
text="Sum(Dictonary((12 30, 46 72, 87 1043)), Dictonary(1 1, 439534 431213.343, 4343 3))"
def f(x):
    return x[0]+', 00 00'
print(sub(r'(\d[\d\s,.]+\d?)',f,text))

# Sum(Dictonary((12 30, 46 72, 87 1043, 00 00)), Dictonary(1 1, 439534 431213.343, 4343 3, 00 00))
```